# C++ recursive linear search fails

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing this simple code of linear searching using recursion, but still getting some problem.
Always getting false as return value.

The code is as follows:

```
 main()
{
    int arr[10] = {12,13,75,23,6,45,90,41,61,56};
    int i, j, num;
    cout<<"  Find number :- ";
    cin>>num;
    bool check = find(arr, num, 0, 10);
    cout<<"   check = "<<check<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

bool find(int arr[], int key, int first, int size)
{
    if(first > size)
        return false;
    else
    {
        if(arr[first] == key)
            return true;
        else
            find(arr, key, first+1, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What result do you get? what result do you expect?

Comment: this is for search, say, if i enter 45, i still get false. should be getting true since 45 exist in array.

Comment: Please improve the formatting of the code in the question. How does the actual behaviour differ from the actual behaviour?

Comment: Compile with warnings, you will get something like `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` which basically tell that there is a missing `return` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add **return** before to launch the function

```
bool find(int arr[], int key, int first, int size)
{
    if(first > size)
        return false;
    else
    {
        if(arr[first] == key)
            return true;
        else
            return find(arr, key, first+1, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

```
if(first > size)
    return false;
```

This should be >= not >, or else you'll end up trying to access past the bounds of the array, below.

```
    if(arr[first] == key)
        return true;
    else
        find(arr, key, first+1, size);
```

Here, you need to remember to explicitly return the value of find(). Otherwise you'll just get a garbage return value instead (which coincidentally happens to be false).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simple enough

first of all you have to check till 9th index only because the index starts from 0 and ends at 9. 
otherwise it may cause run-time error.

take care of declaration of functions and and header files.